# Easymock Unexpected method call error when EasyMock.expect() is specified

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, easymock

I kept running into the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerderTest > testCreateConnector FAILED
java.lang.AssertionError:
  Unexpected method call Worker.getConnectorType("sourceB"):
    Worker.getPlugins(): expected: 3, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$124447d.getConnectorType(<generated>)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerderTest.testCreateConnector(DistributedHerderTest.java:344)
```

even though I put in:

```
    EasyMock.expect(worker.getConnectorType(CONN2)).andReturn(ConnectorType.SOURCE);
```

Code can be found here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/3812

Advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `Worker.class` to `@PrepareForTest({DistributedHerder.class, Plugins.class})`.